# How do I exclude text from table of contents numbering?

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

[image]I have text (my name) with the page numbers in the top right of the page. However, when I go to my table of contents, it shows the number along with the text. So like in the image, it shows "Name - 1", but I would like it to be just "1" for that section in the table of contents. How do I achieve this? Thanks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
%Paragraph jumps and indentation
\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

%Border
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
%Double spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
%Packages
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyheadoffset{0cm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}%
}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\text{Name}~~--~\arabic{page}}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newcommand{\di}{i}          
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\setcode{utf8}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%Images


%Equation numbering
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\urlstyle{same}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}


\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\section{x}





\clearpage
\section{y}


\end{document}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? The MWE doesn't compile on `pdfLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`.

Comment: @User23456234 Let me try and fix it, im using overleaf

Comment: @User23456234 I have changed it so that it shows no errors on overleaf but it does compile there with some extra packages, not sure which are needed etc

Comment: "However, when I go to my table of contents, it shows the number along with the text. I would like just the number as a normal table of contents would be" I'm honestly having trouble understanding what this means. Please try rephrasing.

Comment: @User23456234 I rephrased the question with an image, does it make sense now. Basically, a normal table of contents will only have the number of the page written on it. However, my table of contents has "Name - 1" rather than just the number since I have added my name to each page along with the number. So, LaTeX is treating my name (the text) as part of the number.

Comment: You have redefined `\thepage` to contain your name.  Don't do it.  Instead, add the name in the `\fancyhead` arguments.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Do you mind clarifying? So do I remove the \thepage line and add my name somewhere else? If so, which line in the fancy head argument do I add it and how? Thanks

Comment: @DhruvNair -- The answer has taken care of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that I think you want something like this: (I've slightly changed the right header in my suggested code. I think the dash in your MWE looks too much like a minus sign and, of course, page numbers usually aren't negative.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
%Paragraph jumps and indentation
\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

%Border
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
%Double spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
%Packages
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyheadoffset{0cm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
%\fancyhead[R]{\text{Name}~~--~\arabic{page}}
\fancyhead[R]{%
    Name%
    ~\textendash{}~%
    \thepage%
}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  %\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}%
}
%\renewcommand{\thepage}{\text{Name}~~--~\arabic{page}}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newcommand{\di}{i}          
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\setcode{utf8}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%Images


%Equation numbering
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\urlstyle{same}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}


\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\section{x}





\clearpage
\section{y}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, this is what I was looking for thanks!